# Proper way to record video/live stream with PyQt and openCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to record live stream with my PyQt5 GUI. The live stream part is working fine. But the recorded video file is empty.

Here is the ui file:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(972, 667)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 630, 451, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 630, 451, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(24, 19, 931, 591))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Start Stream"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Record"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "TextLabel"))
```

And here is my main file:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import cv2
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time
from record import *

class WebcamVideoStream :
    def __init__(self, src, width = 640, height = 480) :
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
        self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
        self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 5)
        self.FPS = 1/30
        self.FPS_MS = int(self.FPS * 1000)
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()
        self.started = False
        self.read_lock = Lock()

    def start(self) :
        if self.started :
            return None
        self.started = True
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()
        return self

    def update(self) :
        while self.started :
            (grabbed, frame) = self.stream.read()
            time.sleep(self.FPS)
            self.read_lock.acquire()
            self.grabbed, self.frame = grabbed, frame
            self.read_lock.release()

    def read(self) :
        self.read_lock.acquire()
        frame = self.frame.copy()
        self.read_lock.release()
        return frame

    def stop(self) :
        self.started = False
        if self.thread.is_alive():
            self.thread.join()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback) :
        self.stream.release()



class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_cam)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.recordImage)


    def start_cam(self):
        self.capture = WebcamVideoStream(src = 0).start()
        self.timer=QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setTimerType(QtCore.Qt.PreciseTimer)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_frame)
        self.timer.start(2)

    def update_frame(self):
        self.image=self.capture.read()
        self.displayImage(self.image)

    def displayImage(self,img):
        qformat=QImage.Format_Indexed8
        if len(img.shape)==3:
            if img.shape[2]==4:
                qformat=QImage.Format_RGBA8888
            else:
                qformat=QImage.Format_RGB888

        outImage=QImage(img,img.shape[1],img.shape[0],img.strides[0],qformat)
        outImage=outImage.rgbSwapped()

        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(outImage))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        return outImage

    def recordImage(self, img):
        self.fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
        self.out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', self.fourcc, 10, (640,480))
        self.out.write(img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainW = MainWindow()
    mainW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Also, while I am using `self.recordImage(self.image)`in my `update_frame` function only one frame is recorded as video.

**Edit:**
When I am only using opencv I can write the video with no problem. In PyQt, I am getting the empty outputs.

Looking for a proper way to record the video.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your codec is `XVID` , I think it should be `MJPG` cos you are trying to write on `.avi` . Also it seems like no relation with pyqt tag so you should edit the question

Comment: MJPG is also creating empty output. Also, when i am only using opencv the writing is working as well. XVID is not the problem there. Its not working when i am trying to do the same in pyqt. So, i think pyqt is related somehow. Can you reproduce it with MJPG?